# How to use forEach loop in angular 2 without using ngFor?

Tags: angular, foreach

I am new in angular 2 and I want to access the details of the array through `forEach` loop and some condition on it. Then I want to publish that data by `ngFor`. This was quite easy for angular 1 (by angular.forEach loop). How can I use `forEach` loop in my component to make changes on the data?

Comment: yourArray.forEach?

Comment: So you have array and on some event it needs to be edited and exposed to other components?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach: you really need to learn what you can do in JS with arrays. Given your description, what you actually want is filter, not forEach: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @Dieterg thanks,it works

Answer (score 1):

In .ts file you use like,

```js
for (var key in data.Result) {
    console.log(data.Result[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the silly question guys,but finally i got the exact answer that in angular 1 we are  **using angular.forEach()**  loop and in angular 2 we are using:

```
for(let val of yourArray;let key of index){
     console.log(val);
     console.log(youArray[key]);
 }
```